# Establish standard output communication between java application and external program without starting it

Tags: java, stdout, chess, bufferedwriter

I'm trying to find a way to establish a stdout-based communication between my java program (chess engine) and an external program (chess gui). It's important to notice that the external program is starting my java-app with a little bash script executing the .jar file. The java-app should be able to send commands to the external program through stdout. At the moment, only the communication from external program to java is working.
This is what I tried:

```
try {
        log = new FileWriter("log.txt");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IOException on initializing FileWriter 'log'.");
    }

    while (true) {
        try {
            stringInput = input.readLine();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("IOException on reading Buffered Reader 'input'.");
        }

        if (stringInput != null){
            try {
                log.write(stringInput + "\n");
            } catch (IOException ex){
                System.out.println("IOException on writing to FileWriter 'log'.");
            }

            switch (stringInput){
                case "uci\n":
                    System.out.println("uciok");
                    break;
            }

        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
```

I expect the java program to store incoming commands in the log.txt file, while I should be able to see commands coming from the java-app in the debugging console of the external program.

log.txt indeed is storing incoming commands. 
There's no trace of output from the java-app being received by the external program though.

Comment: The connection is specified in the bash script, you need to [edit] your post and include the script so we can see the redirection that you set up.

Comment: Ok thanks so far. 
Shame on me, I didn't explicitly set up any type of redirection. So I'll look that up.